# Making `export LESS=R` persistent across sessions in fish

Tags: git, macos, less, fish, iterm2

New to the command line here

My title may be a case of classic x/y problem where it describes the attempted solution instead of the problem itself.

Nevertheless, my issue is with `git log` where it prints directly into the command line instead of moving into the pager(?) and clearing the screen afterwards with q.

instead of typing this:

```php
git log
```

I have to type this:

```php
git log | less
```

I've tried all of the following:

```php
git config --global core.pager less
```

```php
git config --global core.pager "less"
```

```php
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less R"
```

to no avail.

I tried this as well

```php
export LESS=R
```

and it worked but only for the current session and did not persist into the next.

Any pointers?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How to add exports to fish like in .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33845/1694970)

Answer (score 0):

You want a universal variable: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#shell-variables

```bash
set -Ux LESS R
```

Just do that once at a command line, do not add it to config.fish.

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like all I needed to do was add `export LESS=R` to my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

I added this line per Brian’s comment on my question above. They [link to a “site duplicate” here](https://askubuntu.com/q/33845/1694970)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).